# Finding roots of nontrivial equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following nontrivial equation:

```
    fun[z_] := (Log[Gamma[n]] + n Log[Gamma[z + 1]] + z n Log[n] - Log[Gamma[n (z + 1)]])/n
    fun[z] /. n -> 8
    m = Table[i, {i, -1, 1, 0.1}] 
    sols = Table[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, 1}], {i, Length[m]}]
    sols2 = Table[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[j]]}], {i, Length[m]}, 
        {j,   Length[sols]}]
```

Basically, I get roots from the equation that are stored in `sols`. However, I also need all values from `sols` as starting values for the next iteration that will be executed in `sols2`. However, this doesn't work and produce the following errors:

```
    {{FindRoot[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["fun", "\[Prime]",MultilineFunction->None]\)[z] +0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[j]]}], 
    FindRoot[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["fun", "\[Prime]",MultilineFunction->None]\)[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[j]]}], 
    FindRoot[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox["fun", "\[Prime]", MultilineFunction->None]\)[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[j]]}], 
    ....
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you aware that *Mathematica* has `LogGamma[]` built in?

Comment: @J.M.Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 6):

Let's polish up your code a bit...

```
With[{n = 8},
 fun[z_] := (LogGamma[n] + n LogGamma[z + 1] + z n Log[n] - LogGamma[n (z + 1)])/n;
 m = Range[-1, 1, 1/10];
 Map[(z /. First[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 1/2 == #, {z, 1}]]) &, m]
 ]
```

Some notes:

- You don't really need or want the last step in your question here; a far better route would have been to tweak the options of `FindRoot[]`, as well as finding better initial estimates for your roots.
- I have elected to use the built-in `LogGamma[]` function here, which avoids all the problems of a construction like `Log[Gamma[z]]`. (There's something strange about having to deal with large numbers just to get a reasonably-sized result...)
- `Range[]` is as useful as `Table[]` for generating a list of numbers in arithmetic progression, and should be always kept in mind.
- `Map[]` is useful if you want to run some function through the elements of a list.

Comment: Do you show `Range` and `Map` rather than `Table` just to teach it as an option, or do you find is superior in this case? (+1 by the way)

Comment: A bit of both, actually. After all, in this specific case there is the much more compact `Table[z /. First[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 1/2 == k, {z, 1}]], {k, -1, 1, 1/10}]`, but the approach here also works if `m` had been some random array of numbers...

Comment: One could also use `Table[. . . , {k, m}]` in that case. (Telling anyone reading, not you J.M.)

Comment: Oh, it's fine. I actually forgot that `Table[]` can work like a `foreach()` construct these days.

Answer (score 4):

Syntactically correct version of `sols2` is

```
 sols2 = Table[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[j, 1, 2]]}], 
 {i, Length[m]}, {j, Length@sols}]
```

using  `fun[z]` as in Mark's answer.

However, this does not serve your purpose for two reasons:

First, the solution of equation `i` from `sols` is used as starting value for the search for the root of equation `j` (for different `i` and `j`) in the second round which is not likely to improve the results. Perhaps, you meant to use a single index as in:

```
 sols2 = Table[FindRoot[fun'[z] + 0.5 == m[[i]], {z, sols[[i, 1, 2]]}], 
 {i, Length[m]}]
```

Second, considering the error  message you get for both `sols` and `sols2`

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

you need to consider playing with the options for `FindRoot` as J.M. suggested in his answer and comments.

EDIT: Inpecting the plots could suggest an explanation of the numerical results.

Plotting three examples from the 21 equations:

```
 Row[Plot[fun'[z] + 0.5 - m[[#]], {z, -3, 3}] & /@ {1, 15, 21}]
```

[image]

So, as the region `z<=-1` seems hopeless, one needs to restrict root search to the appropriate region (`z>-1`).

Next, plotting all 21 functions

```
 Plot[Evaluate[(fun'[z] + 0.5 - m[[#]]) & /@ Range@Length@m], {z, -1, 5}]
```

[image]

we get a hint as to why the first 14 equations are solved without any issue while the last 7 are not. In particular, equation 15 simplifies to

```
  FindRoot[fun'[z] == 0, {z, 1}]
```

Note that `Limit[fun'[z] ,z->Infinity]=0` and `fun'[z]` is strictly increasing on `(0,Infinity)` ([This reference](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X04003348) and citations therein on complete monotonicity properties of `Gamma`  and related functions). These observations together with the fact that

```
 fun'[0] = - 0.513416 < 0
```

explain why the equation `fun'[z]==0` does not have a solution in `[0,Infinity]`. By the same reasoning, equations 15-21 (which differ from equation 15 by a constant) do not have a solution in  `[0,Infinity]`.

Comment: Nice analysis! :)

Comment: @kguler Thank you. Your deep analysis helps me in understanding more about my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your `fun` depends upon `n` and, though you plugged in `n->8` at line 2, your subsequent code doesn't refer to that line.  Thus, `FindRoot` receives input that doesn't return numerical output.  That's the source of the error.

I don't see the purpose behind the two steps, as in both steps you're solving equations of the form `fun'[z]+0.5==c`, where `c` is constant.  These are easily solved.

```
fun[n_, z_] := (Log[Gamma[n]] + n Log[Gamma[z + 1]] + 
  z n Log[n] - Log[Gamma[n (z + 1)]])/n;
f[z_] = fun[8, z];
FindRoot[f'[z] + 1/2 == -3/10, {z, 0}]
```

{z -> -0.321733}

Comment: It would seem that OP is trying to polish the results in `sols`...

Comment: @Mark. I need the second step,i.e.`sols2` to refine the root to certain range.

Comment: @Wayan: the refinement doesn't work very well here in this case. You'd be better off changing `FindRoot[]`'s options, or even trying to find a better starting estimate for `FindRoot[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your suggestion.